# Issue with stacking of the columns in google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
function drawVisualization() 
 {

 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable
 ([
  ['Month', 'Lifting', 'Listing', 'Target'],
  ['Jan',  300, 1200, 322],
  ['Feb',  425, 1500, 400],
  ['Mar',  400, 1400, 380],
  ['Apr',  650, 1800, 625],
  ['May',  500, 1700, 530],
  ['Jun',  700, 2000, 650],
  ['Jul',  800, 2500, 750],
  ['Aug',  650, 2200, 700],
  ['Sep',  500, 1800, 525],
  ['Oct',  525, 1400, 475],
  ['Nov',  650, 1700, 675],
  ['Dec',  500, 1900, 600]
   ]);

      var options = {
      title : 'No. of cars which are listed and whether the lifting is on target',
      vAxis: {title: 'No. Of Cars'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {0: {type: 'stack'}},
      series: {1: {type:'bar'}},
      series: {2: {type: 'line'}},
      legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
      bar: { groupWidth: '75%' },
      isStacked: true
                       };

             var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
 chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

I want to stack the two columns over one another but in such a way that listing bar is started from bottom,so I'm not so sure about stack.So how can I achieve this. I'm using google charts.

Comment: I want to overlap my columns bars over one another

Comment: You say Stack and Overlap but those two are different actions in Google Charts. I believe you need to simply use the "isStacked: true" .
Check out this one : https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#stacked-bar-charts

Comment: Ok i got it now,i doesn't want stacking.I want to overlap the multiple columns values over each other.So can you help me out with this stuff@Strahdvonzar

Comment: I am not aware of Google Charts natively supporting Overlapping. 
You can always though "fake" overlapping by just creating a Stacked Graph and a bit "normalization" on your Data in order to provide the Overlap effect. 

It is a bit complicated to analyze it here , so you better check this discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/7i0mliS7iHU

You will understand what needs to be done. Its more in the Data you will provide than the Coding the Charts. You have to "manipulate" your data before feeding them in your Chart to achieve the overlap effect.